# 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath when deploying to jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss

i have a spring boot application that i try to deploy on jboss. it works on tomcat 7 and tomcat embedded, but on jboss i get the error presented in the title.

the pom.xml is the following:

```
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

        <aspectj.version>1.9.2</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tomcat</id>

            <properties>
                <dependency.artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</dependency.artifactId>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>jBoss</id>

            <properties>
                <dependency.artifactId>spring-boot-starter</dependency.artifactId>
                <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<!--                    <scope>com</scope>-->
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>default</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <dependency.artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</dependency.artifactId>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>${dependency.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <optional>true</optional>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.interceptor</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.interceptor-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.22.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

running the command mvn clean install -PjBoss would generate me the war file for jboss.

when deploying the app, i get that error and i believe it is because of the POM(i know it looks bad, but i fought with it the entire day, sorry)